# Want to stop Photoshop from opening at OS X startup

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, osx-yosemite, auto-login

Photoshop opens when I startup my iMac with Yosemite 10.10  I have checked off *Open at Login* and my System Preferences do not have an *Accounts* icon in order for me to stop auto login for Photoshop. Photoshop opens anyway.

Comment: In your System Preferences you should see *Users & Groups* though. Can you turn off Photoshop there, in case it's listed under *Login Items* for your account? When you shut down your Mac, do you always quit all apps before?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the photoshop icon in the Dock.

Go to "Options" and uncheck "Open at Login".

Comment: for me although this option was unchecked it keeps opening on startup. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually use Photoshop regularly & have it open when you shut down your Mac? It could be that a new feature introduced since Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) called “Apple Persistence” is getting in the way. To disable it, open up the Terminal by going to `Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal` and type in this command:

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no
```

More details [can be found here](https://www.mikesel.info/disable-osx-application-persistance/):

> One feature which seems to divide the masses is OS X’s ability to
>   relaunch your applications on startup/reboot. This feature is know as
>   Apple Persistence, which is personally a feature I am not really a fan
>   of. It’s very rare for me to want the same applications on each use of
>   my MacBook, asides from the obvious email and unified comms clients of
>   course.

Comment: Doesn't this setting pertain to the automatic saving of version history for files, which is actually a *good* thing? I don't think this is related to login items—or restoring of open windows upon restart—in any way. See also [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52390/611).

Comment: I see, thanks. But it *does* actually do versioning too, so one should be aware of that if they disable it.